# jQuery, access div inside a div

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="pic">
  <div id="left">
    <img src="images/left.png" />
  </div>
  <div id="right">
   <img src="images/right.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the `div` with `id` "right" when I click on the `div` with `id` "left"

Code I am using:

```
$("#left").click(function(){$("#right").hide();});
```

This is not working, what is the reason? And how will I achieve what I intend to?

Comment: your code is pretty basic… can you show your entire html?

Comment: Works for me. Do you have these elements many times in your page?

Comment: Hey Kobi, you are correct.. i just tested this code.. there is some other problem.. though i dint repeat any name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are one of three things wrong, since your code is technically correct:

1. Your click function does not appear in your `$(document).ready` function
2. Your page repeats ids. Use classes instead.
3. Your divs are created dynamically and therefore not bound on `$(document).ready`

(1) is a simple fix. Just put in your `$(document).ready`. (2) just change your `id` attributes to classes, but if you want to make sure that you hide the correct div you may need to do some traversing. (3) can be fixed by using `$(selector).bind('click', function(){});` or `$(selector).live('click', function(){});`

Good luck

*UPDATE (1/24/12)* - If you're using jQuery 1.7+, you should use `$(selector).on('click', function(){});`, not `bind()` or `live()`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct and works for me.

Something else is wrong.

Try setting up the handler in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#left").click(function() { $("#right").hide(); });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be fine, but looks like you are missing the [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)'s `ready` event, try this:

```
$(function(){
 $("#left").click(function(){
   $("#right").hide();
  });
});
```

**Note:** `$(function(){` is short form of `ready` event code.

Comment: @srk: are your divs dynamically generated?

Answer (score 1):

The click event can only be added after the #left div has loaded. For this reason wrap your existing jquery in a domready call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#left").click(function(){$("#right").hide();});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

1. did include the jquery.js file in the html head
2. are there no bugs in the preceding javascript before that jquery line? They could stop execution before reaching that point.
3. are the id's unique? Maybe you have multiple elements with id='right'?